# Redirects and masking with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I've got a domain like `domain.com` and a path in it like `/path` so that `domain.com/path` redirects to another server entirely (let's say `128.10.10.10`).

This works, but I'd like to set it up so when I'm at `128.10.10.10` after the redirect the URL bar at the top of the browser reads `domain.com/path` and so that any subfolders therein would be accessible via `domain.com/path/subfolders`.

Any idea how to do this? The server (`128.10.10.10`) is running Apache and CentOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you'll want a reverse proxy:

```
ProxyPass /path/ http://128.10.10.10/
ProxyPassReverse /path/ http://128.10.10.10/
```

When you do this, you'll no longer redirect traffic to 128.10.10.10. Traffic will flow through domain.com to 128.10.10.10. The 128.10.10.10 web process will see the traffic coming from domain.com, not from the end-user.

You can read more details at [Apache's mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: So I don't need to change my `<VirtualHost 128.10.10.10:80>` block? I just throw those details in `httpd.conf` somewhere?

Comment: You'll need to put the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` configurations in the `domain.com` configurations, not the `128.10.10.10` configurations.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. Cheers.